# SQL QUERY ON EXISTS CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

1) Query:

```
SELECT INS_NAME
  FROM INSTRUCTOR 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT DEPT_NAME
                FROM DEPARTMENT
               WHERE DEPT_ID = INSTRUCTOR.DEPT_ID AND DEPT_BUILDING = 'JOHNS');
```

2) Query:

```
SELECT INS_NAME
  FROM INSTRUCTOR 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT DEPT_NAME
                FROM DEPARTMENT
               WHERE DEPT_BUILDING = 'JOHNS');
```

codes 1 and 2 produce different outputs please help me understand the reason.

(INSTRUCTOR TABLE)

```
ins_id ins_name dept_id ins_sal tax
27     DHIRAJ    4        200
28     RAHUL     4        500   
34     HIO       4        100    2
90     SURYA     5        120    30
33     VINNY     6        100    11
```

(DEPARTMENT TABLE)

```
DEPT_BUILDING    DEPT_NAME  DEPT_ID
THOMAS           BIO       4
JOHNS            CHEM      5
JOHNS            CSE       6
```

Comment: Any reason for using an exists rather than a join?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Salmon , I was just testing out with exists no other reason for not using join .

Answer (score 2):

The second query returns all records from the `instructor` table because there are 2 records in the `department` table where `DEPT_BUILDING='JOHNS'`. Thus the `exists()` returns true for every record.

The first query returns only the last 2 records from the `instructor` table because the `exists()` also tests for a match in the department id and department no 4 does not have a building called johns.

Comment: Yeah, got the difference . Thanks !!